# 4º principio del software libre

Tags: linux

En una conferencia, Richard Stallman hablando de los principios del software libre dijo que "El software libre debe permitir la distribución de copias modificadas por un programador, inclusive permitir su venta."

¿Con esto a que se refiere? ¿Un programador está legitimado a modificar una versión para luego poder venderla y obtener beneficio?

No me ha quedado muy claro. He leído las explicaciones sobre free y gratis y no me ha quedado claro en qué caso estoy yo vendiendo un software y a su vez permitiendo su libre distribución. ¿Podría alguien coger una distribución gratuita, modificarla y venderla?

Comment: Hola Ivan, bienvenido. Aquí se resuelven problemas relacionados con la programacion, pero errores, dudas o problemas con el código. Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia y fuera del alcance de este sitio.

Comment: Eso dependerá del tipo de licencia que elijas para distribuir tu software. Las hay más restrictivas y menos. Stallman aboga por un tipo de licencia nada restrictiva, y todo lo que no sea ese modelo, no lo considera Software libre estrictamente.

Comment: Aunque he votado para cerrar la pregunta hablando en el chat me han comentado que hay algunos temas que no son de programación que estarían aceptados, entre ellos las licencias de software, así que podría ser una pregunta válida.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no tiene que ver con ningún tema de programación

Comment: Esta pregunta se ha cerrado, reabierto y vuelto a cerrar. Como ya he dicho me comentaron que era un tema aceptado, se votó aquí: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%c3%b3n-de-la-tem%c3%a1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio/163#163. Hay otras discusiones sobre el tema y parece que hay consenso en aceptar preguntas tipo "programmers"

Answer (score 1):

Sí. Desde el punto de vista de Richard Stallman, donde **libre** hace referencia a libertad (*free as in freedom*), y no a cerveza gratis (*but not as in free beer*), tu estás legitimado a hacer lo que quieras con "tu libertad respecto al programa", incluso revenderlo, modificado o no, siempre y cuando no restringas la libertad de terceros (si lo redistribuyes gratis o no, modificado o sin modificar, lo que has redistribuido debe seguir siendo libre).

Es decir, que si tú quieres publicar un software que sea libre desde la definición dada de Stallman a libertad, debes de poner una licencia a tu software de modo que asegure los puntos que he mencionado arriba:

1. Indicar en la licencia que el usuario puede hacer lo que quiera (y que el código sea accesible es una condición necesaria para eso).
2. Pero: indicar que está prohibido hacer dicho software privativo más tarde. Es decir, que tu redistribución debe seguir respetando el punto 1, (si no, cometería un delito porque incumple la licencia).

Bajo esta definición, la GNU Fundation mantiene la licencia GPL, que es una licencia llamada viral porque obliga a redistribuir, no solo con cualquier otra licencia libre, sino otra vez con la GPL, o una licencia compatible con la GPL.

A su vez, la GNU Foundation mantiene una [lista](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html) de licencias libres, según son compatibles con la GPL (que puedas redistribuir el software con esa licencia en vez de la GPL), parcialmente compatibles con la GPL (que puedas añadir componentes nuevos a tu software con una licencia diferente a la GPL), o incompatibles legalmente con la GPL pero todavía libres (bajo su definición de software libre).

También hay otras licencias libres pero bajo otra definición de "libre":

- Las licencias *open source*: licencias más prácticas, orientadas a que el código fuente debe ser público, pero no para "proteger las libertades de los usuarios" (que el software no haga cosas que no dice hacer, por ejemplo), sino orientadas a que todo el mundo pueda ver el código para poder "ayudar a mejorarlo" (la visión de Linus Torvals)
- o las licencias de dominio público: se puede hacer literalmente lo que te de la gana, como privatizarlo luego (como la Creative Commons 0).